# how to pass pipe data in expression engine query

Tags: ee2

this is my  expression engine query

```
$query =  $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_categories WHERE parent_id=$parent_id order by cat_id ASC");


and $parent id = 4|7 (for category parent id passed from template by user)
```

now query should return result for both parent id's

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing SQL queries

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this really an SQL or PHP question?

I think you'd need to split the pipe delimited data up (say by using explode() to create an array) and then loop through it outputting a fragment of SQL each time and build your query up.

SQL syntax would be (not the full query);

```
 WHERE parent_id = 4 OR parent_id = 7 ORDER BY
```

Or:

```
WHERE parent_id IN (4,7)
```

Comment: Robson's edit is the simpler way to do it, just replace the pipes with commas and you're good to go!